# Cantor's derived sets

Tags: real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Does there exist a compact subset $P$ of reals for which $P^n \neq P^{n+1} \forall n\geq0$ ( $P^{n+1}$ is derived set of  $P^{n}, P^0=P$) and ${P^\infty} \neq \emptyset$ ($P^\infty=\bigcap_{n=0}^{n=\infty}P^n$)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are such sets. To describe an example, let's start with simpler tasks.

- If we just want $P\ne\emptyset$ with $P^1=\emptyset$, take $P$ to be a singleton.
- If we want $P^1\ne\emptyset$ and $P^2=\emptyset$, take $P$ to be a strictly increasing sequence together with its limit $a$. Then $P^1=\{a\}$.
- If we want $P^2\ne\emptyset$ and $P^3=\emptyset$, then take $P$ such that $P^1$ is a strictly increasing sequence together with its limit $a$. For instance, start with such a sequence $a_0<a_1<\dots\nearrow a$. Let all these points be in $P$, together with, for each $i>0$, a strictly increasing sequence sitting betwen $a_{i-1}$ and $a_i$ and converging to $a_i$. Note that $P^1=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}\cup\{a\}$.
- We can recursively extend these examples to produce, for each $n$ an example $P$ with $P^n\ne\emptyset$ and $P^{n+1}=\emptyset$. To see this, note that any $P$ so built has a minimal point, some points that are successor points, meaning that they have an immediate predecessor in $P$, and some points that are limits of sequences of points in $P$. We build the next example: For each successor point $b$ in $P$ with immediate predecessor $b^-\in P$, fix a strictly increasing sequence sitting strictly between $b^-$ and $b$ and converging to $b$. Let $Q$ be the union of $P$ and (the ranges of) all these sequences. Note that $Q$ is closed and that all points of $P$, except for its least element, are limit points of elements of $Q$, so $Q'$ is just $P$ with its least element removed.

Ok, we are ready to build the desired example. Let $P_n$ be a set built as in the procedure just described, with $P_n^n$ a singleton. By means of a dilation and a translation, we may also ensure that $P_0=\{0\}$, $P_1\subset(0,1/2]$ with $\max P_1=1/2$, $P_2\subset(1/2,3/4]$ with $\max P_2=3/4$, and so on, with $P_n\subset(1-1/2^{n-1},1-1/2^n]$ and $\max P_n=1-1/2^n$ for all $n>0$.

Now set $P=P_0\cup P_1\cup\dots\cup P_n\cup\dots\cup\{1\}$.

---

In fact, you can ensure much more. For each countable [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) $\alpha$ there is a closed countable set of reals $P=P^0$ such that $P\supsetneq P^1\supsetneq\dots\supsetneq P^\beta\supsetneq\dots\supsetneq P^\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$ (at limit stages $\gamma$, define $P^\gamma=\bigcap_{\rho<\gamma}P^\rho$). An easy way to achieve this is to note first that each countable ordinal embeds into $\mathbb R$, and that we may further ensure that the embedding is continuous (where the ordinal is given the order topology). We then just note that successor ordinals are compact, and that their derived sets are easy to compute. For instance, the limit points of an ordinal $\alpha$ are just the limit ordinals below $\alpha$. The limit points of this set are the ordinals below $\alpha$ that are multiples of $\omega^2$, and so on.

In the examples above, each set $P_n$, $n>0$, has order type $\omega^n+1$ and $P=P_\omega$ has order type $\omega^\omega+1$ (the exponentiation is in the ordinal sense).

(To see that any countable ordinal embeds into $\mathbb R$, in fact note that any countable linear order embeds into $\mathbb Q$, as can be easily verified by constructing the embedding recursively using an enumeration of the linear order and the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in itself and has no endpoints. Once such an embedding of an ordinal is arranged, consider the closure of its range. Check that this is again an ordinal, perhaps slightly larger than the ordinal you began with, and redefine the embedding accordingly, to obtain a *continuous* embedding.)

It is perhaps worth pointing out that mention of ordinals is not an accident or capricious. For instance, theorem 2.1 of

> [MR0867644 (88a:05013)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=867644). Baumgartner, James E. *[Partition relations for countable topological spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(86)90059-2)*. J. Combin. Theory Ser. A **43** (1986), no. 2, 178–195,

implies in particular that if $X$ is a countable Hausdorff space with a countable open base, $0<\alpha$ is countable, and $X^\alpha\ne\emptyset$, then $X$ has a subspace homeomorphic to $\omega^\alpha+1$.

Comment: Following your construction in first part, if in each step, I add $\{-1/n\}$ (n varying over naturals) to all points obtained in previous step and so on, finally I am left with all negative rationals (including limits which are also rationals). Then $P$ is not closed.

Comment: No, that is why I ensure that each new sequence sits between points of a previous one. At the first stage you have, say $0,1/2,3/4,7/8,\dots,1$. At the next stage you have a sequence between 0 and $1/2$ converging at $1/2$ (for instance, $1/4,3/8,7/16,15/32,\dots$), a sequence between $1/2$ and $3/4$ converging at $3/4$, and so on. In the next stage you add a sequence between $1/4$ and $3/8$ converging to $3/8$, one between $3/8$ and $7/16$ converging to $7/16$, and so on. No limit points other than the ones explicitly listed appear in the process.

Comment: (So, for instance, 0 is not in $P^1$ since it is not a limit point of $P$, $1/4$ is not in $P^2$, etc.)

Comment: I still don't get it, lets consider adding $\{-1/2,-1/4,-1/8,...\}$ each time. All terminating binary expansions in $(-1,0)$ will be covered, isn't it?

Comment: For example, $-(0.10011)_2=-1/2-1/16-1/32$

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "each time", or what your example means.

Comment: Anyway, I will write a different example that perhaps you will find clearer.

Comment: I have modified the example, perhaps this new version is clearer and illustrates how we could continue transfinitely.

Comment: @SaurabhPurohit What do you have in mind when you add elements of $P$ (as in $-1/2-1/16-1/32$)? Neither the question not the answer involves addition of elements of $P$, so how is this sum relevant?

Comment: @Saurabh I think I finally understand the confusion. When I wrote that you add to $P$ a sequence, or words to that effect, what I meant is that you form a new set consisting of the union of $P$ together with the range of this sequence. I am not actually considering sums of elements. I have modified the language to avoid mentioning sums.

Comment: Please correct me in which step I am wrong (or just tell me what will $P^1$ look like). Considering the $P$ you made-
1. Each $P_n$ is range of a convergent sequence and has only one accumulation point.
2.$P^1$ is a convergent sequence.
3. $P^3$ is empty.

Comment: @Saurabh All three steps are incorrect. For the sets that I call $P_n$, I suggest you first play with a few of them to understand what $P_n^1$ is. For the set $P$ itself, $P^1=P_0^1\cup P_1^1\cup\dots\cup P_n^1\cup\{1\}$. Now, $P_0^1=\emptyset$, $P_1^1=\{1/2\}$, $P_2^1$ is the union of $3/4$ and a strictly increasing sequence converging to $3/4$, etc.

Comment: I understood the construction, it is wonderful. 
For strictly decreasing ( in proper subset sense) derived sets, is taking derived sets and intersection of previous derived sets similar to the way ordinals are defined (superscript of $P$ being an ordinal)? And can $P^{\omega_2}$ be non empty set, because  cardinality of $\omega_1$ is  $\aleph_1$ which is the same as cardinality of reals.

Comment: I'm glad this helped. A nice result that essentially ends up being a consequence of the fact that the rationals are countable is that if $P$ is a closed set of reals, then either $P$ is countable and $P^\alpha=\emptyset$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$, or else $P$ contains a perfect subset, in which case there is a countable stage $\alpha$ such that $P^\alpha=P^{\alpha+1}=\dots$ is perfect. (Note also that perfect sets of reals have size $|\mathbb R|$, and therefore any uncountable closed set of reals also has this size.)